# Executor.execute() hangs definitely

Tags: java

Im doing nashorn lately and so went to read about the java.util.concurrent.

Ive an issue where i can run simple executors like :

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool();
new ThreadPoolExecutor();
```

The snippets of code runs, but after the task is over the console process doesnt stop like if it hangs waiting something.

Any reason why this happens ?

Comment: Run in a debugger, get to the point of the hang, look to see what's going on.

Comment: Im runing a simple hello world print inside execute, thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those executors are spawning non-daemon threads which are preventing the JVM from exiting.

Try shutting down the executors when you are done with them using:

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Wow ty u just comfirmed my doubts. But please one more thing, i had to create a separate thread to test executor.getCompletedTaskCount() before i can do shutdown(), would you suggest a different design pattern to shutdown executors after they are done ?

Comment: shutdown() allows executing tasks to finish. shutdownNow() forces the executor to shut down instantly.

Comment: Ty again and it seems i no need another thread just shutdown() does the trick.